# Mouse event getAction name

Tags: android

I am trying to find out the Action Name that is being performed by the mouse. I tried

```
String act=String.valueof(event.getAction());
```

it returns me integer `3`.
Can anyone guide me with the list of integer associated with motionevent in android.

Comment: There's no such thing as mouse events on Android. And please, read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) before asking.

Comment: i want to know that if you type event.MOUSE_UP or any action related...we get an integer value in return. So can any one guide me if i am getting an integer value 3,than which event the mouse is calling..

Comment: It's in the link I gave you above. Read it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear if anyone actually answered this question but regardless of the pedantry of whether it is a non-existant mouseevent or a `MotionEvent` @Satyam asked how to get the **name** of the action ***not*** its value!! Instead of criticizing the questioner, or highlighting his knowledge gap, for not reading. it behoves the answerers to actually read the question. This should be used:

```
MotionEvent ev 
me.actionToString (me.getAction());
```

It is very useful when logging an app's progress while debugging. I wish there was a similar method for the `DragEvent` but I have to take a longer path...

Answer (score 0):

You can put code like,

```
int action = event.getAction();
switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //code here....
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //code here....
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //code here....
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        //code here....
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL

`MotionEvent` class have all listed event for finger touch

Comment: I have gone through the google document, but i am not able to find out to which action integer value 3 is associated.

Comment: I am sure you don't go through complete otherwise you found it. If you click on this link you got the value for 3 for Action name

Comment: This values are constant value of an Action for example ACTION_CANCEL is  Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as mouse event on Android. You probably meant `MotionEvent`s. You have the description and explanation of each action in the [official SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) (which btw you should read **before** asking).

Answer (score 0):

`

```
private static String getActionName(MotionEvent event) {
   try {
       for (Field f : MotionEvent.class.getFields()) {
           if (f.getName().startsWith("ACTION_") &&
               f.getInt(null) == event.getAction()) {
                   return f.getName();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {}
    return event.getAction()+"";
}
```

`